# Cartesian equation of a trochoid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A trochoid is defined by the following parametric equation:

$x = r\cdot\theta-d\cdot\sin(\theta)$

$y = r - d\cdot\cos(\theta)$

When $r = d$ the analytical form is

$x(y) = r\cdot\cos^{-1}(\frac{r-y}{r})-\sqrt{y\cdot(2\cdot r - y)}$

Is there also a cartesian form when $r <> d$?

The goal is to derive a formula for the intersection points of two arbitrary trochoids.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You can more easily solve for $ \theta_1, \theta_2  $ from separate parametric forms without merging x- and y- equations the transcendental equations numerically

$x = r1\cdot\theta_1-d1\cdot\sin \theta_1 = r2 \cdot\theta_2-d_2\cdot\sin \theta_2 $

$ y = r1 - d1\cdot\cos \theta_1 = r2 - d2\cdot\cos (\theta_2 ) $

Comment: I do not quite understand: shouldn't it be: $x = r_1\cdot\theta_1-d_1\cdot\sin(\theta_1) = r_2\cdot\theta_2 - d_2\cdot\sin(\theta_2)$ and $y = r_1 - d_1 \cdot \cos(\theta_1) = r_2 - d_2\cdot \cos(\theta_2)$? But it is exactly the question how to find a solution for this.

Comment: Indeed  typo just about to correct it.

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not see a way how to solve these equations for specific $d_1,r_1,d_2,r_2$'s

Comment: Some technique to handle self-intersecting  muti-valued curves is to  be found. Numerical/graphical method works.